# sqlexception was unhandled

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

"Invalid object name 'TableName_Tombstone'" reads the rest of the exception message. 
I'm trying to sync sqlce with sql server 2008 and although I've attributed the TombstoneTableName a name with the following code:

```
TableNameBuilder.TbombstoneTableName = TableName.TableName + "_Tombstone"
```

It appears not to find it on the server db although I did activate change tracking.

more details: 
i've also tried to access the tombstone table with the following code, but pointless:

```
TombstoneTableName = "Sales." + tableName + "_Tombstone",
```

any clues?

Answer (score 1):

You can run SQL Server Management Studio.  Open the Object Explorer (File > Connect Object Explorer...) and connect to the target SQL Server server.  In the Object Explorer tree view, navigate to Databases > {your database name} > Tables.  Look at the list of tables to see if the table may have been created with a different name.

By the way, what are the values in TableName.TableName and tableName in your C# code?